# What is the maximum size for the postMessage method that enables inter-frame communication?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

It's not clear from searching on Google and looking through documentation. What's the maximum length on a message sent via `Window.postMessage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)? We assume this varies by browser?

Comment: there is not a hard-set limit per the spec. you can move data much faster with transferable objects, several hundred MB/s. Normal String messages bog down after a just few dozen MBs. the cap will vary between devices and browsers. test your code for the environments you want to support.

Comment: could you add this as an answer please? thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As a data point, the WebKit implementation (used by Safari and Chrome)
doesn't currently enforce any limits (other than those imposed by running
out of memory).

Source : https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2009Oct/0546.html

Comment: Is this still the case?

Comment: This link appears broken, could probably find it in a mailing list archive but it says http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2009-October/235564.html+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in&client=firefox-a  is down

Comment: @ColinD This link is broken as well :)

Comment: Right, that is what I meant by the comment is that the whole link is down. I went ahead and found the thread in another mailing list archive https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2009Oct/0546.html